# Вывод уникальных элементов массива и их суммирование

Tags: javascript

Неудобно спрашивать, но нет времени на поиски метода выполнение данной задачи. А закончить нужно уже сегодня вечером в чистовом виде. По этому заранее извиняюсь!

Есть массив данных:

```
Id:  9 Name: 1 Voice: 1
Id: 10 Name: 1 Voice: 1
Id: 11 Name: 2 Voice: 1
Id: 12 Name: 3 Voice: 1
Id: 13 Name: 1 Voice: 1
Id: 14 Name: 2 Voice: 1
```

В общем нужно выводить лишь уникальные значения и их суммировать при совпадение.

Сейчас у меня код которые выводит без сортировки и суммирования:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetVotings","Chart")',
    }).done(function (votings) {
        var labelsArray = [];
        var dataArray = [];
        $.each(votings, function (index, data) {
            labelsArray.push(data.Name);
            dataArray.push(data.Voice);
        });
        renderChart(labelsArray, dataArray);
    });
});
```

Comment: Уникальность по какому признаку и что суммировать? Код Ваш даже близко это не решает.

Comment: Я и написал что кроме функции вывода данных, данный код сейчас нечего не делает, а нужно чтоб выводилось лишь уникальный Name и при совпадение Name, Voice суммировалось.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто: во временном объекте храним ключом `name`, а значением - индекс этого объекта в новом массиве.
Проходим по данным циклом и проверяем - если такой `name` есть во временном объекте, то прибавляем `voice` в новом массиве по индексу. Иначе заносим новый `name` с новым индексом.

```js
// Переводим строку в массив объектов
// Лень ручками в массив перевести :)
let data = `
Id:  9 Name: 1 Voice: 1
Id: 10 Name: 1 Voice: 1
Id: 11 Name: 2 Voice: 1
Id: 12 Name: 3 Voice: 1
Id: 13 Name: 1 Voice: 1
Id: 14 Name: 2 Voice: 1`.trim().split("\n").map(e => {let r = {}, a = e.split(/\s+/);a.forEach((e, i) => i === 0 || i % 2 === 0 ? r[e.toLowerCase().replace(':', '')] = +a[++i] : null); return r;});

// Возвращается массив с уникальными ключами name и сплюсованными значениями voice
// Из примера вернётся массив с 3-мя объектами:
/*
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": 1,
    "voice": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": 2,
    "voice": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": 3,
    "voice": 1
  }
]*/
let usedName = {}, newArr = [];
data.forEach(e => e.name in usedName ? newArr[usedName[e.name]].voice += e.voice : usedName[e.name] = newArr.push(e) - 1);

console.info(newArr);
```